# Running a command on multiple files using TCL script

Tags: file-io, tcl, simulation, synopsys-vcs

I am using a certain tool (Synopsys Design Vision) which I am running by using a TCL script.

The command is something like this

```
analyze -library work -format verilog {/user/codes/abcd.v }
```

Now I have a folder with 5000 .v extension files with names abcd_1, abcd_2, abcd_3.....abcd_5000. Now I want to automate the script so that the command works on each and very file.

I tried to do something like this

```
for { set a 1}  {$a < 5001} {incr a} {
analyze -library work -format verilog {/user/codes/abcd_$a.v }
#other commands
.
.
}
```

However, it is not working and giving error. I have not worked with tcl scripts that much.

Kindly specify where I am going wrong and what can I do to make it work. Thank you.

Comment: Tcl braces prevent variable expansion, just line single quotes in the shell. Use double quotes instead.

Comment: Note that your quoting style makes the space after ".v" important. Do your files actually end with "dot v space"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut it short, use quotes rather than braces, as the latter prevent [variable substitution](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M10) from happening:

```
for {set a 1}  {$a < 5001} {incr a} {
  analyze -library work -format verilog "/user/codes/abcd_$a.v"
  # ...
}
```

However, you might also want to check out the `file` command to assemble file paths.